# Hiding All Apple Music Features in iTunes (Apple Music Menus, Radio, Connect & Heart Column)

Tags: itunes, apple-music, macos

I want to uninstall Apple Music from iTunes.
I don't really care of this so expensive new 'revolution' and it's taking too much place... :/

[image]

For example how to delete  'For you, New, Radio and Connect'

[image]
And the heart

By the way, all my music is on local and I don't need cloud, radio or anything else.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Sorry to say, but I think these UI elements are baked into the app. I can't find any user preferences to remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go into `Preferences > General` there's two things that you need to uncheck to disable *Apple Music*.

1. `Show Apple Music`
2. `iCloud Music Library`

For the *Connect* Menu, you can do this by going into `Preferences > Parental` and checking the `Apple Music Connect` tickbox.

Now I'm not entirely sure what ticking the `Internet Radio` box does in `Preferences > Parental` but it doesn't seem to hide the Apple Music Internet Radio button. I currently haven't found a way to hide this radio button.

**Edit:** Hiding the heart column in iTunes is simple enough. Just right click the `heart` column in iTunes and scroll down till you see the `Love` option that's ticked.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the hearts, you can open iTunes > Preferences > General and set "Ratings" to be "Stars".

Answer (score 0):

Apple Music is baked into the current version of iTunes and you can't really "uninstall" it. That said there is an option to minimize its impact:

in iTunes > Preferences > general un-check "Show Apple Music"

I don't use Apple Music either and after reading [this post](http://www.loopinsight.com/2015/07/22/apple-music-is-a-nightmare-and-im-done-with-it/) (loopinsight.com, July 22, 2015), I'm glad I never did as Apple Music seems to be a bit buggy and can actually delete music you added yourself.